# Why am I fighting the TypeScript compiler with so many type assertions?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, type-assertion

I'm new to TypeScript, and I find that I have to frequently add type assertions to compensate for the compiler's chronic inability to narrow types. This makes me wonder if the TypeScript compiler has substantial limitations or if I am doing something wrong (or at least non-idiomatic).

Specific example ([TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=2&jsx=0&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors=true#code/MYGwhgzhAEDiCWAvAtgewDwBUB80DeAsAFDTTCoB2EALgE4Cuw1qtAFAA63wBuY1AptF4h6-AFzRMASnwBfYqTBNWMvGUoRUIfgDoQqAOatqAC3gQdw0VIDc0eUQfkq1aABN+AMzD0Q1BCio0AC80BT8AO5wSGisACwATLbQAPQp0YHoFPTIAEb8tNjExGnQBjFB5tCo7NTwlGAg0PCeks0w2XkF0KwR-ADkIE30EIIe3r7+FVIANNWmBRHmgvDU-TC0-ACO9PCbbjrE1ACe7IIA8rUQWLihmND8AB4CFG4dOfm0CqTQAPz4nlQqF+EhoXAoBjm5UCIIyaBuDh+0AkeEBwNBdHgEKhFQkAXhOFkNiOp0EAGFKJ54AYbiFoAAlba7fboS7Ua44bDEogldLncLQdhgWhgZD8AS0aCmPjtaq1eoURrNVr3KqdT5zTY7Pb8NzzEyLZaHIgnM7QACCtAMHNubSeLzeYQ+3X+AG02TbfgBdZHQd1XG5e7meegUJgK6DIMAAa34FIoVJp91C6oK2FYOkzrpq7LpeFk0Eg0A9tJSACoy+aKykvRJLdablIJPHE7TCCR1C58NC0KkKwAhat08Y+Pz41AF0I5iDc0ibaj0WgUfDfUhoiT9EeTfozVdlXH7wKFmCh6MUVARZdF8c3Oblstk6t7zM6ae7jsFoun8+X4-QFvUjcdj3gAIk+jjFEQUaxgBRhSDoPaoDoSjUCo3LQXGlLUqweCIRI4RROOrD9JAbieP0UiyPBiHIcotjEEAA)):

```js
class Gizmo<T> {
  constructor(private value: T) {}
  act() { console.log(this.value); }
}
const defaultGizmo = new Gizmo(42); // Gizmo<number>

// gizmo is optional if T is number (we'll use defaultGizmo), otherwise it's required.
type Opts<T> = T extends number
    ? {foo?: string, gizmo?: Gizmo<T>}
    : {foo?: string, gizmo: Gizmo<T>};
type Config<T> = Required<Opts<T>>;

// One parameter that is optional if T is number, required otherwise.
type Args<T> = T extends number ? [Opts<T>?] : [Opts<T>];
function makeConfig<T = number>(...[opts = {} as Opts<T> /**A**/]: Args<T>): Config<T> {
  const {gizmo /**B**/ = defaultGizmo} = opts;
  return {
    foo: 'default',
    gizmo: gizmo as unknown as Gizmo<T>, /**C**/
    ...opts,
  } as unknown as Config<T>; /**D**/
}

makeConfig().gizmo.act();
makeConfig({gizmo: new Gizmo('asdf')}).gizmo.act();
```

Notes about the above code:

- At comment `/**A**/`: Why is the `as Opts<T>` type assertion necessary? Without it, the compiler complains:

  > Type `{}` is not assignable to type `Opts<T> | Opts<T>`.

  But it is assignable because `{}` is only used if `T` is `number`, and `Opts<number>` has no required properties.
- At comment `/**B**/`: Why does `gizmo` have type `Gizmo<number>` here? It should be `Gizmo<T>` because `opts` has type `Opts<T>`. (The `defaultGizmo` value should only be assigned if `T` is `number` because otherwise `gizmo` is a required property in `opts`.)
- At comment `/**C**/`: This type assertion is necessary to work around the fact that `gizmo` has type `Gizmo<number>`.
- At comment `/**D**/`: Why is this type assertion necessary? The object provides all of the required properties with their required types.

If the type assertions are required due to compiler limitations, can my code be refactored to work around the limitations without any type assertions? I'm worried that the type assertions will mask actual bugs.

Comment: **A**: `{}` is *not* assignable to `Opts<T>`. Hence why the compiler would give you an error then. And you've silenced it with a type assertion.

Comment: **B** and **C**: `defaultGizmo` is `Gizmo<number>` and that would not necessarily match `T`. The caller determines the generic argument, they could have called `makeConfig<string>` and yet you want to use `number` instead.

Comment: @VLAZ If the caller sets `T` to a type other than `number`, then the `{}` at **A** will never be used because the compiler will require the user to supply an `Opts<T>` argument to the function. Similarly, the `defaultGizmo` at **B** will never be used because the user will be required to set `gizmo` in their `Opts<T>`. Shouldn't the compiler understand these cases?

Comment: But how do you determine that at the line `opts = {} as Opts<T>`? You are saying that *for any `T*, an empty object applies. But if `T = string` then it does not. In fact, it only applies for `T = number` which you cannot determine at this point in time. Imagine having the logic `if (userWants != "apple") giveUser("orange")`. That isn't correct because the user may want a sandwitch instead but you're always giving them an orange. Same thing with your generic - the caller is free to specify things as they want but your logic only works in one case.

Comment: @VLAZ If `T = string` then the false branch of `Args<T>` will be taken, and the compiler will require the caller to provide an `opts` argument of type `Opts<string>`. You can try it: `makeConfig<string>().gizmo.act()` will cause the compiler to error with "Expected 1 arguments, but got 0." Similarly, `makeConfig<string>({gizmo: defaultGizmo}).gizmo.act()` will error with "Type `Gizmo<number>` is not assignable to type `Gizmo<string>`."

Comment: Richard - I see what you're saying about the default only being used when `T extends number` because if it doesn't, `Opts<T>` requires `gizmo` to be present. @VLAZ - I think it's probably reasonable to say that yes, this is a limitation of the compiler? But Richard, even if it didn't have that limitation (if that's true), there'd be a different problem: Remember that `27` extends number, so `Opts<T>` would allow no `gizmo`, but `Gizmo<42>` is not applicable to `Gizmo<27>`. I think your best bet here is two separate functions (or carefully-curated type assertions).

Comment: (If going for the carefully-curated type assertions, I'd use a function overload for clarity, but that's a matter of opinion.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Good point about `27` extending `number`. However, I tried replacing `T extends number` with https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27024#issuecomment-931205995 and it still required the type assertions. `gizmo`'s type at **B** was widened to `Gizmo<T> | Gizmo<number>`, so that's progress.

Comment: Yes -- my point was that even without the potential limitation of the compiler, you'd still have that problem, not that it would fix the issues related to the potential limitation.

Comment: Personally, I think `makeConfig` should do less work.  It worth splitting function logic. For instance, it might be a good idea to create default gizmo data structure and call `makeConfig` only ifr `opts` is not an empty object. It will be easier to read and understand what function does. Now, it is not clear, at least for me, what this function should do